# How to compare two images in JavaCV and draw rectangles the part which is different in these two images

Tags: image, javacv

I want to compare two images by using JavaCV, and draw a rectagle in part which these to images are not the same like example below.

[image]

I tried the code below, but it needs one image as input, and will draw rectangle on all the objects in the image.

```
IplImage img=cvLoadImage("image_path_and_name.jpg");
        CvSize cvSize = cvSize(img.width(), img.height());
        IplImage gry=cvCreateImage(cvSize, img.depth(), 1);
        cvCvtColor(img, gry, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvThreshold(gry, gry, 200, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        cvAdaptiveThreshold(gry, gry, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 5);

        CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
        CvSeq contours = new CvContour(null);

        int noOfContors = cvFindContours(gry, storage, contours, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, new CvPoint(0,0));

        CvSeq ptr = new CvSeq();

        int count =1;
        CvPoint p1 = new CvPoint(0,0),p2 = new CvPoint(0,0);

        for (ptr = contours; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.h_next()) {

            CvScalar color = CvScalar.BLUE;
            CvRect sq = cvBoundingRect(ptr, 0);

                System.out.println("Contour No ="+count);
                System.out.println("X ="+ sq.x()+" Y="+ sq.y());
                System.out.println("Height ="+sq.height()+" Width ="+sq.width());
                System.out.println("");

                p1.x(sq.x());
                p2.x(sq.x()+sq.width());
                p1.y(sq.y());
                p2.y(sq.y()+sq.height());
                cvRectangle(img, p1,p2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0);
                cvDrawContours(img, ptr, color, CV_RGB(0,0,0), -1, CV_FILLED, 8, cvPoint(0,0));
                count++;

        }

        cvShowImage("contures",img);
        cvWaitKey(0)
```

;

output:

[image]

If any one knows how to do this, please let me know. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes I have found the solution, OpenCV can do this, but before you must learn how to use OpenCV process image

Comment: can you post some code or steps to do the stuf , thanks

Comment: 1. Exceute the method `absdiff();` to get the absolute defference of two images,
2. Use `cvCanny();` method one the result return by `absdiff();`
3. Find the counters by `cvFindContours();` and the counters will be save in the `CvSeq`.
 set mode to  `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL`.
4. Loop the counters as bellow:
`for(CvSeq c = contours; c != null && !c.isNull(); c=c.h_next()) {
   double area = cvContourArea(c, CV_WHOLE_SEQ, 0);
   
   if(area < 100) {
    continue;
   }
   CvRect rect = cvBoundingRect(c, 0);
   cvRectangleR(dst, rect, RED, 2, 8, 0);
  }`
 `cvShowImage("Example", dst);`